# How to add http headers to Firebase HttpsCallable function's response

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it not possible to add headers to response? This code returns error when I add this header.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export default functions
  .https.onCall(async (_, context) => {
    context.rawRequest.res?.setHeader(
      "Strict-Transport-Security",
      "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    );

    return { message: "Hello World" };
  });
```

```js
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Without header it works fine, but I need to add some headers to the response. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to change the details of the [callable function protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  The client and backend SDKs maintain full control of the HTTP request and response.  You can only specify the JSON contents of the body in either direction.

If you need control over the headers, you should not use a callable function and instead write a normal [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Comment: Since callable functions can be called via HTTP as well, I except to modify it.

Comment: As I said, that's not supported.

Comment: I know :) I leave it as a feedback to Firebase Developers. Thanks anyway @Doug

Comment: The best place to leave feedback is Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I required the same thing. I wanted to add "access-control-max-age" header to reduce preflight requests but blocked by this fact unless there is some workaround? By default callable function doesn't puts this header and so it defaults to 5 seconds and triggering preflight after every 5 secs for the same request.