# Firebase Callable Function: How to restrict CORS origin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Callable Functions supports CORS by default. This is good, but it seems to allow requests from any origin by default. How how do I restrict CORS requests to specific origins?

For example, here is a preflight request example (simplified for demonstration purposes):

```
OPTIONS /callFunctionName HTTP/1.1
authority: us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net
access-control-request-method: POST
access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type
origin: https://foo.example.com
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Response (simplified):

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example.com
Content-Length: 0
```

As the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` responds with the request origin, the CORS request will always be allowed by the browser. How can I restrict this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like CORS configuration is now supported

```
const { onCall } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
exports.getGreeting = onCall(
  { cors: [/firebase\.com$/, "flutter.com"] },
  (request) => {
return "Hello, world!";
  }
);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible. Response headers for callable functions only allow `Content-Type` and  an optional `charset`. If you need control and restrict CORS or any part of the [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) that deviates from what's implemented by Firebase Callable Functions, you should instead use a normal HTTP function and implement those details as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580393/7031308).

To handle a preflight request using HTTP function, you must set the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-* response headers.

Here's a sample nodejs code that handles preflight request:

```
/**
 * HTTP function that supports CORS requests.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // and caches preflight response for 3600s

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'your-allowed-origin');
  // Allows GETs from your specified origin with the Content-Type header

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

Alternatively, you can use a third-party library to handle CORS for you.

You may also refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#preflight_request) for more information.

Comment: This looks like an HTTPS cloud function endpoint. Can you set the http response headers with callable functions as well?

Comment: Hi @JohnnyOshika, I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Seems like an oversight by Firebase. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I added a feature request to customize allowed origins in callable functions here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Pull Request was submitted that allows us to white-list cors origins for callable functions: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/986

The PR was closed due to changes in upcoming API design, but it sounds like the Firebase team is working on adding this option.

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/882

Comment: Has this been implemented yet? It would be very useful.

Comment: @digibake I don't believe it has